# Почему в VirtualBox работает общая папка но не работает буфер обмена. Host: Windows 11, ОС в VBox Debian 10

Tags: debian, virtualbox

Почему в VirtualBox работает общая папка но не работает буфер обмена. Host: Windows 11, ОС в VBox Debian 10.
При этом установлен гостевой ОС, буфер выставлял как на Двенаправленный, так и на Из основной в гостевую.
Debian работает как ssh-host

Comment: А Вы что, прям на гостевой консоль юзаете? А через ssh сессию не? Ну и попробуйте Ctrl+Shift+V на гостевой для вставки или Shift+Ins

Comment: Да, благодарю за ответ, вчера разобрался, черел Сетевой мост подключился в Putty, также из через ssh можно

Comment: Поставьте Windows Terminal прям из стора, сконфигурите папку  .ssh на хосте в домашней с ключами и не морочтесь с пути.